# fixing the following diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I managed to create the following automaton drawing, and I am trying to fix it so that:

1. the loops do not go over each other in state 0
2. the r and t edges between q_0 and q_1 are properly set up (maybe curved a bit or whatever is needed for them not to go over each other)
3. same for x, s

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.text,topaths,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=0.25ex]


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_2) [below=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  [loop above] node {$y$} ()
          edge  node [swap] {$t$} (q_1)
          edge  node [swap] {$s$} (q_2)
          edge  [loop above] node {$s$} ()
    (q_1) edge  [loop above] node {$t$} ()
          edge  node [swap] {$r$} (q_0)
    (q_2) edge  [loop above] node {$r$} ()
          edge  node [swap] {$x$} (q_0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (for some reason, the code doesn't show properly even though I marked it.)

Comment: It's because it was placed immediately after a list, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item I fixed it by adding a  comment, as you can see from the revision history. Welcome to the site!

Comment: The points two and three seem to be already "fixed", unless I'm not getting what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Alenanno, the two edges should be distinct. Right now there is an arrow with two arrowheads, but it should be two curvy lines with separate arrows (one towards q_0 one towards q_1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with use `bend left` edge option and `loop below` for the second loop at `q0` node:

[image]

and `quotes` library for shorter code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    node distance=2cm and 2cm, 
    bend angle=20,
    auto            ]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)         {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting, right=of q_0] (q_1)   {$q_1$};
   \node[state,accepting, below=of q_1] (q_2)   {$q_2$};
   \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  [loop above,"$y$"] ()
          edge  [bend left,"$t$"] (q_1)
          edge  [bend left,"$s$"] (q_2)
          edge  [loop below,"$s$"] ()
    (q_1) edge  [loop above,"$t$"] ()
          edge  ["$r$"] (q_0)
    (q_2) edge  [loop above,"$r$"] ()
          edge  ["$x$"] (q_0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

¸

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible approach, I wouldn't be surprised if you get other answers.

You can use `bend left=<angle>` as an option to the `edge`s to separate them. For the loop, you can modify the `looseness` and `in`/`out` angles. Note that you need to set the end node for the loop in that case.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.text,topaths,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={remember picture,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=0.25ex}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_2) [below=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  [loop above]     node {$y$} ()
         % add bend left=10, remove [swap] from the node
          edge  [bend left=10]   node  {$t$} (q_1)
          edge  [bend left=10]   node  {$s$} (q_2)
          edge  [loop above,
                 % increasing looseness makes the loop bigger
                 looseness=12,
                 % change the start/end angles of the loop
                 out=110, in=70] node {$s$} (q_0) % added q_0 as end node
    (q_1) edge  [loop above]     node {$t$} ()
          edge  [bend left=10]   node {$r$} (q_0)
    (q_2) edge  [loop above]     node {$r$} ()
          edge  [bend left=10]   node {$x$} (q_0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can play around with the `in` and `out` angles of the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.text,topaths,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,inner xsep=0,inner ysep=0.25ex]


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state,initial,accepting] (q_0)   {$q_0$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$q_1$};
   \node[state,accepting] (q_2) [below=of q_1] {$q_2$};
    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge  [in=120,out=150,loop] node {$y$} ()
          edge  [in=170,out=10] node [above,swap] {$t$} (q_1)
          edge  [in=125,out=-35] node [above,swap] {$s$} (q_2)
          edge  [in=30,out=60,loop] node {$s$} ()
    (q_1) edge  [loop above] node {$t$} ()
          edge  [in=-10,out=-170] node [below,swap] {$r$} (q_0)
    (q_2) edge  [loop above] node {$r$} ()
          edge  [in=-55,out=145] node [below,swap] {$x$} (q_0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]